# Properties / Property: getter doesn't work! Objective-C iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, position, positioning

in my programm, I made a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *block;
@synthesize block;
```

-

now if I do:

```
NSLog(@"BLOCK = %i", block.center.y);
```

It just says:
BLOCK = 0

but my block UIImageView object never is on y = 0!

please help!

Comment: you are not using the getter anyway. To use the getter you have to use self.block = foo;

Comment: fluchtpunkt: You should post an answer to the question, not simply reply with a comment.

Answer (score 2):

`CGPoint.y` is `CGFloat`, so you need to use `%f` to print it out.

Answer (score 1):

A property and an instance variable are different things; a property represents state exposed by your class, while an instance variable is one way you can implement state for your class.

When you wrote `block.center.y` you were accessing the *instance variable* named `block`, not invoking the property getter.  To invoke the property getter you must always use either dot or message syntax, such as:

```
CGFloat centerY;

centerY = self.block.center.y;  // sends -block getter to self
centerY = [self block].center.y;  // sends -block getter to self
```

Here's an example where all of these differ:  `isEnabled_` is the instance variable, `enabled` is the property, and `-isEnabled` is the getter method invoked by the property:

```
@interface View : NSObject {
@private
    BOOL isEnabled_;
}
@property (getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
@end

@implementation View
@synthesize enabled = isEnabled_;
@end
```

The `getter=isEnabled` attribute tells the compiler to generate `-isEnabled` messages when getting the `enabled` property.  The `@synthesize` defines the `enabled` property as being backed by the instance variable `isEnabled_`.

You can therefore access the property this way:

```
BOOL shouldDrawView;

shouldDrawView = someView.enabled;  // sends -isEnabled to someView
shouldDrawView = [someView isEnabled];  // also sends -isEnabled to someView
```